# Issue with Apache-ranger setup

Tags: docker, apache-ranger

We are trying to setup Apache ranger using docker image using the commands mentioned below

```
mkdir -p ${HOME}/git
            cd ${HOME}/git
            git clone https://github.com/apache/ranger.git
         cd ${HOME}/git/ranger
      
    
          export ENABLED_RANGER_SERVICES="tagsync,hadoop,hbase,kafka,hive,knox,kms"
            ./ranger_in_docker up
```

Though we have all the pre-requisites setup done but are getting an error.

ranger-base exited with code 0

ranger-build | [ERROR] Could not create local repository at /home/ranger/.m2/repository -> [Help 1]

ranger-build | [ERROR]

ranger-build | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

ranger-build | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

ranger-build | mv: cannot stat 'target/version': No such file or directory

ranger-build | mv: cannot stat 'target/ranger-*': No such file or directory

ranger-build exited with code 1

WARNING: Found orphan containers (ranger-build) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.

Building ranger

[+] Building 0.5s (8/14)

=> [internal] load .dockerignore 0.0s

=> => transferring context: 411B 0.0s

=> [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile.ranger 0.0s

=> => transferring dockerfile: 2.81kB 0.0s

=> [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ranger-base:latest 0.0s

=> [ranger 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ranger-base:latest 0.1s

=> [internal] load build context 0.1s

=> => transferring context: 274B 0.0s

=> CANCELED [ranger 2/8] RUN update-java-alternatives --set /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 0.4s

Can someone please help with the way-out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we are looking to install ranger through docker and getting above mentioned issue even though all pre-requisites are installed.

Comment: I have tried creating manually the folder /home/ranger/.m2/repository and running the command as sudo but still doesn't work. I get the same error.